# issue using Microsoft Help Viewer 1.1 in windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there any issue/problem/error/bug using Microsoft Help Viewer 1.1 in windows Server 2008 ??

Any help in this regard is highly appriciated.
thanks in advanced

Comment: What is *your* problem with the Help Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no issues using Help Viewer 1.1 in Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm a fan of Aaron's response for it's simplicity and +1'ed it, I'm taking a wild guess that the issue you're seeing is detailed in [KB917607](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917607).  If that's the case, you may need to download the appropriate WinHlp32.exe viewer from the aforementioned article.